# Need file save dialog for android

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

I need file save dialog for android, to save my app generated png files.

I tried `Intent intentFileSave = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);`

But this didn't work.
In case, I don't have any file manager, **Is android have default "save as" dialog ??**

I also tried to integrate **OI File Manager** in my application.
But I don't know, is the license of *OI File Manager* permits to use it as a library.

Is there any other option to ask user to pick location and name of the file ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586691/how-to-open-file-save-dialog-in-android ... also, there's [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/).

Comment: Quote from Eric's "this" link: The standard API does not include file dialog to select files or directories.

Answer (score 3):

> Is android have default "save as" dialog ??

No, mostly because apps either save the files in their app's portion of internal or external storage, or save them in the specific public directories named in the `Environment` class. They then use `ACTION_SEND` to share files with other services that can consume them.

> But I don't know, is the license of OI File Manager permits to use it as a library.

I do not see any sign of a license in their GitHub repository for the source, which is unfortunate.

> Is there any other option to ask user to pick location and name of the file ?

Beyond not doing it at all (and saving to standard locations), you can:

- Link to file manager apps like OI File Manager via their specific `Intent` actions (e.g., `org.openintents.action.PICK_DIRECTORY`), prompting the user to install one if there is none
- Poke around for some other library for choosing a directory and/or file
- Create your own

Comment: If you can use OI File Manager as a file selection dialog by passing an Intent to it i don't think the license matters, since you're not linking to it in any way?

Comment: @Torp: Yes. I presumed that the OP wanted to actually integrate the source code ("permits to use it as a library").

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I want to integrate the source code with my project as a library. But I shouldn't do it, right ? You told me to launch it via Intent action, but if OI File Manager is not installed then it is not prompting me to install it in my emulator.  
Is there any way to give OI File Manager as my application's pre-requirement ??

Comment: @themilan: "Is there any way to give OI File Manager as my application's pre-requirement" -- unfortunately, no. You can use `PackageManager` to find out if it (or anything that you support) is installed, then prompt the user to go download one from the Play Store. You can even use a `market:` `Uri` to send them to the right screen within the Play Store app.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried,

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/*");
```

But It shows me every possible intents such as FileManager, Gallery, Music, Contects, etc...
I didn't find any way the android decides possible intents that support "Save As" feature.

So, I have following solution.
Here, I just need to add more and more tries for different file explorers that support **Save As** feature.

```
int iLoop = 0;
int iTryCount = 2;
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < iTryCount; iLoop++)
{
    Intent intent = null;

    if (iLoop == 0)
    {
        // OI File Manager
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setData(startDir);
        intent.setAction("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
        intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.TITLE", "Save As...");
    }
    else if (iLoop == 1)
    {
        // AndExplorer
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setDataAndType(startDir,
                "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");
        intent.putExtra("explorer_title", "Save As...");
        intent.putExtra("browser_filter_extension_whitelist", "*.png");
        intent.putExtra("browser_line", "enabled");
        intent.putExtra("browser_line_textfield", "file1.png");
    }

    if (intent != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to launch activity
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SAVE_FILE);

            // TODO: Remove this notification on Publish
            Toast.makeText(m_baseSurfaceView.getContext(),
                    "Try : " + iLoop, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // If everything gone well, then break from here
            // otherwise see catch(..) block
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            // If all tries are done, then conclusion is that,
            // the user needs to install some file-manager application
            // to locate where to save the file
            if (iLoop == iTryCount - 1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(
                        m_baseSurfaceView.getContext(),
                        "Please Install some File Manager"
                                + " application to locate destination.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please comment if any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The OI File Manager doesn't need a license to use it because it's a self-contained piece of software. Think of the Open Intents project as an API of sorts. APIs don't need licenses, as far as I know.

As for saving a file, unfortunately the OI File Manager doesn't give you a "Save As" option, but you can easily work around that! Just have the user input the file name they want in your app, then use the [PICK_DIRECTORY intent](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/165) to let them tell you where to put it!