# How do I get the available space using android scoped/shared storage?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, diskspace, scoped-storage

Within my app the user is prompted to create a zip file using intent ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586691/how-to-open-file-save-dialog-in-android))

This returns a content URI to my app, similar to: `content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2Fbackup.zip`

This is the backup file that my app will write to after the user has picked a location. I need to check if the selected location has enough space for the file, because the file can get very large, up to more than 1GB.

The problem is, that I can't find a proper, standardized way to check if the amount of bytes I'm going to write to the file fits within the free space of the user-selected folder. Many of the old approaches don't work, since I can't access the file system directly.

I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#query-free-space) solution from the docs, but it only seems to adress files that are within the apps private, scoped storage.

`StorageManager` and `StorageStatsManager` also don't seem to work, as they seemingly can't understand content-uris, but only standart Java-`File` objects that I can't use.

How do I do a simple check on how much space is available?

Comment: Note that `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` is not limited to the filesystem. It can include network servers, cloud storage services, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I know and it doesn't cause any problems creating & writing to the zip file if there is enough space.

Comment: "is enough space" is not necessarily simple to answer, though, which is why AFAIK it is not part of the Storage Access Framework protocol.

Answer (score 1):

By using [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage), retrieving primary (external) storage's free capacity is possible without any permission:

```kotlin
val freeBytesOfPrimary = DocumentFileCompat.getFreeSpace(context, StorageId.PRIMARY)

val freeBytesOfSdCard = DocumentFileCompat.getFreeSpace(context, "9016-4EF8")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see /primary in the content scheme then you use storage of device. If not from removable micro sd card.

You can determine storage space and storage free space in the old fashioned way using file parhs.

Have a look at the paths returned by getExternalFilesDirs().